# Leaflet change color of markers (R)

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm trying to make a map with the leaflet package in R. My goal is to color the markers on the map based on a factor variable in my data frame. The dataframe I'm working on is something like this:

My code is as follows:

```
subset_dados$Circuito=as.factor(subset_dados$Circuito)

pal <- colorFactor("blues", subset_dados$Circuito)

leaflet(subset_dados) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(~Longitude, ~Latitude, color=~pal(Circuito),fillOpacity = 0.5)
```

But the map i get is the following

[image]

I don't understand what i'm doing wrong, since I would like to have a different color for each factor, but it seems that the only thing changing is the transparency of the black.

Thank you!

Update! I'm adding part of the data frame to make the question reproducible.

```
Circuito Latitude Longitude    
L2RC 41.36394 -8.550200
L21M 41.22638 -8.693360
LBXP 41.15796 -8.610030
L2RC 41.36394 -8.550200
LERM 41.23865 -8.531550
LCAN 41.14016 -8.634990
LARE 41.19195 -8.556460
LCAR 41.05805 -8.563920
LBXP 41.15786 -8.600700
LBAG 41.18931 -8.526040
```

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput()`? So we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Quinten I've added part of my data frame to make reproducible! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should have set `Blues` in your `colorFactor` to color the markers based on different `factors`. You can use the following code:

```
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
subset_dados$Circuito=as.factor(subset_dados$Circuito)

pal <- colorFactor("Blues", subset_dados$Circuito)

leaflet(subset_dados) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(~Longitude, 
                   ~Latitude, 
                   color=~pal(Circuito),
                   fillOpacity = 0.5)
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see in the picture, the markers show different colors based on the `factors`.

Comment: Oh, thanks! In other news, do you know any color pallete that could differentiate the markers better? For instance, with different colors instead of different shades of a color? Thank you.

Comment: You can change `Blues` to for example `YlOrRd` which shows the colors between yellow and red which is maybe better.

Comment: This link has some more palettes: https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/colors.html